# How to pull my own private repository's docker image using airflow DockerOperator?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, gitlab, airflow

I'm using Airflow install via Docker image in AWS instance, and I have created a docker image of my project and pushed it to the GitLab container registry.
Now I want to pull this image in airflow to run daily, I know when we pull our own private image we have to authenticate **So How I can login using airflow dag, file, or any method to resolve this problem**.
My code

```
stripetos3_scheduler = DockerOperator(
    task_id='stripe-to-s3',
    image='registry.gitlab.com/mobinalhassan/stripetos3dags:latest',
    auto_remove=True,
    force_pull=True,
    dag=dag
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use imagePullSecrets mentioned here https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes/stable/operators.html

Create a Secret like this

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
name: {{.Release.Name}}-image-pull-secret
namespace: {{.Release.Namespace}}
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: {{ template "dockerConfigTemplate" . }}
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

Create a template which is used by above Secret Component

```
{{- define "dockerConfigTemplate" }}
{{- if .Values.images.airflow.registry }}
{{- $url := .Values.images.airflow.registry.url }}
{{- $name := .Values.images.airflow.registry.username }}
{{- $password := .Values.images.airflow.registry.password }}
{{- $email := .Values.images.airflow.registry.email }}
{{- $auth := (printf "%s:%s" $name $password | b64enc) }}

{{- printf "{\"auths\":{\"%s\": 
{\"username\":\"%s\",\"password\":\"%s\",\"email\":\"%s\",\"auth\":\"%s\"}}}" 
$url $name $password $email $auth | b64enc }}

{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

In my case I'm deploying Airflow (Custom Image which has Dags as well) from my Private Registry

I'm exporting this Secret as a Env Variable which can be used by other components

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: worker-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - args: []
      command: []
      env:
      - name: OI_DATAPIPELINE_IMAGE_PULL_SECRET
        value: {{.Release.Name}}-pipeline-image-pull-secret
```

Now we need to use the above created secret in our Dags as follows

```
data_pipeline = KubernetesPodOperator(
namespace='default',
name="DataPipeline",
task_id="data_pipeline",
image='*********.jfrog.io/*****:latest',
image_pull_secrets= 
[k8s.V1LocalObjectReference('OI_DATAPIPELINE_IMAGE_PULL_SECRET')],
env_from=env_from,
cmds=["./deployments/data_pipeline/start.sh"],
get_logs=True,
is_delete_operator_pod=True,
dag=dag
)
```

Comment: can you elaborate how?

Comment: @DanielM I updated on how to use Secrets while pulling an image from Private Repo

Comment: Can you explain how I can create a secret to pull docker image from GitLab container registry?

Comment: The author of the response is using DockerOperator, why would you give him a "solution" with KubernetesPodOperator?

Answer (score 0):

You should create new connection of `Docker` type via Airflow UI and provide necessary data there:

1. GitLab registry server (not sure about GitLab, but example for DockerHub is `docker.io`)
2. Username
3. Password

Then in your DAG definition you need to pass connection's name to `docker_conn_id` param.

```
stripetos3_scheduler = DockerOperator(
    task_id='stripe-to-s3',
    image='registry.gitlab.com/mobinalhassan/stripetos3dags:latest',
    auto_remove=True,
    force_pull=True,
    dag=dag,
    docker_conn_id="my-connection",
)
```